# Suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are reflexive relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, education

I need some help with this problem, 
Suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are reflexive relations on a set $A$.
Show that $R_1 ⊕ R_2$ is irreflexive?

Comment: If $\oplus$ is symmetric difference, that’s *very* straightforward.

Comment: Ask yourself what reflexive and irreflexive mean and use the definition of symmetric difference.

Comment: Suppose this post had a meaningful title.

Comment: So, $\oplus$ is symmetric difference? That is, $X\oplus Y = X\setminus Y \cup Y\setminus X$? You know what reflexive means? and what irreflexive means?